# How can I set up separate WiFi access in OpenWRT?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I've got a Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH router, and I've got my network set up (with Samba, network printers, etc.), but I would like to set up a separate WiFi network with a different SSID and access only to internet.

I'm using OpenWRT 10.03.1-RC5, r27608, and all the tutorials I find for this seem terrribly out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Even the one at the OpenWRT website: [Configure a guest WLAN](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/guest-wlan)?